# How to deploy mkdocs site on GitHub Pages under *custom directory*

Tags: python, github-pages, mkdocs, custom-domain

The general idea is to have multiple mkdocs documentation sites under a single repository. Like this:

```
- index.html # landing page
  - /product1/getting-started/
  - /product2/getting-started/
```

I use this script `.github/workflows/ci.yml` to deploy master on push

```
name: ci
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.x
    - run: pip install mkdocs-material
    - run: mkdocs gh-deploy --force --clean --config-file ./mkdocs.yml --site-dir ./product1
```

And I use these gh-pages settings (for Custom domain):
[image]

And the only result I can get by playing around the config is this

`www.example.com/getting-started/`

instead of
`www.example.com/product1/getting-started/`